# SQL query to compare individual average with a group average

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table with names and a score. What I would like to do is produce a list of names with their average score, where their average is greater than the average of the group.

I have the following `SQL` statement that works in Access but not my server (running `MySql`):

```
SELECT Person, Avg(Score) AS PersonAverage FROM TblScores GROUP BY Person HAVING (((Avg(Score))>(SELECT Avg(Score) AS AverageOfAllScores FROM TblScores;)));
```

the server is saying that the syntax is wrong but I can't see where. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: There are two semicolons. Remove the first one.

Comment: Unless the parentheses are unbalanced (you have way too many of these), the only problem I see above is the semicolon after `TblScores`. See if getting rid of that fixes your problem. If not, lose all unnecessary parens and end the query with `HAVING Avg(Score) > (SELECT Avg(Score) FROM TblScores)`. Note that you don't need the column alias `AverageOfAllScores` either, though it should be harmless.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks to you both. Massive help. Removed the semi colon and works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the first `;` since it is a statement terminator.

 Change this :

```
SELECT Person, Avg(Score) AS PersonAverage FROM TblScores GROUP BY Person HAVING (((Avg(Score))>(SELECT Avg(Score) AS AverageOfAllScores FROM TblScores;)));
```

with this :

```
 SELECT Person, Avg(Score) AS PersonAverage FROM TblScores GROUP BY Person HAVING (((Avg(Score))>(SELECT Avg(Score) AS AverageOfAllScores FROM TblScores)));
```